# Android/java if else statement in puplic class

Tags: java, android, class, if-statement

I try to modify my app to read from a `MySQL-DB` the content with localized language as a separate column.

The easiest way (dirty workaround) I image, is to change the statement `@SerializedName("name") to @SerializedName("name_de")` with an `if-else`.

```
if(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName().equals("de")){
    @SerializedName("name_de")
}else{
    @SerializedName("name")
}
```

But where and how to put it in the code?

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.*;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.xxxxxxx.storefinder.R;

import java.util.Locale;

public class Category {


    public Category(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
       }

   // @SerializedName("name_de")
   // public String name ="";

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name = "";

    @SerializedName("id")
    public int id;
}
```

Sorry for this noob question.
I just don't understand the underlying concept and just need to localize this app, the easy way

kr

Daniel

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Thank you for your question. My question is: Where and how to put my suggested solution in the code, to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an extra field for the locale display name, please check the example below:

```
public class Category {

    public Category(int id, String name, String locale) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.locale = locale
       }

    @SerializedName("locale")
    public String locale ="";

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name = "";

    @SerializedName("id")
    public int id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to avoid to put a second string in Category(). I would have to make too many changes in other parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

its not the right thing to do, you should read two (or more) fields as separate fields and then try using an interface (adapter) in order to get the right one according to locale at needed time